# 11896/10964 failed to execute script docker-compose, KEYBOARDINTERRUPT

Tags: docker

after i run docker-compose [arguments], it got stuck like forever and given the message :

```
KeyboardInterrupt
[11896] failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Also i get like this after docker-compose up -d

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 129, in <module>
  File "c:\users\docker\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dq7hcd\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in 
load_module
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\docker\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dq7hcd\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 680, in 
load_module
KeyboardInterrupt
[10964] Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap
```

I didn't know how to fix this and I'm really confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, maybe it just can work for some case

`1. Uninstall the Docker`

`2. Reinstall Docker`

My opinion is concerned with the docker version, maybe after updating or installing over and over, it will make chaos with your docker-compose command.

After re-install, I can use docker-compose again without laggy or got stuck.

Too hard searching for documentation, but I want to persuade all contributors here to give an opinion about how it works, and how the error can happen? Thx.